# how to guarantee no py file can be compiled from my custom python interpreter?

Tags: python-2.7, obfuscation, opcode

I'm trying to obfuscate my python code by editing the bytecodes of python in the .c files. something like the idea in this link:
[a link](http://blog.quarkslab.com/building-an-obfuscated-python-interpreter-we-need-more-opcodes.html)link
[another helpful link](http://www.expobrain.net/2013/09/04/simple-hardening-of-the-python-interpreter/)

I know that pyretic (https://github.com/MyNameIsMeerkat/pyREtic) can reverse engineer this approach using the dis module. It compares the resulting dis of a scrambled opcode with resulting dis of a normal opcode.

Of course an attacker can load the dis.py and our custom compiler will compile it to dis.pyc. So, any compiling build-in functionality has to be removed. Like compile_py, and compileall .. etc. how to guarantee they are all removed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the version he is giving in his tutorial ! 
[image: File To Download]

It is a modified version and contain special files that you normally don't have with python 2.7.11 installation. I Tested It

[image: Difference]

The .c files are in the python folder in his version 2.7.6

[image]

Comment: not yet.. I already downloaded his version and i can see the .c files their. I just don't understand how to run his python version. It has setup.py. does this mean i should install it using "python setup.py install" (I believe that is not possible. how can i install python with a python command). what am i missing here?

Comment: Off course the goal is to make a new interpreter ! If you want to try to inspect the bytecode with the dis module you can use your python 2.7.11 Then when you will have build your new interpreter try to inspect it with this new version to see the difference

Comment: so i have to install his version of python using "python setup.py install" after editing the.c files?

Comment: I'm sorry but SO is not a help center, this is not the place for this kind of question. Please accept my answer and fly by your own! :) thanks.